# Convert my EditText Input to an observable stream

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin

So i have been trying to convert my EditText input  that i get from my TextWatcher to an observable of stream but i cannot convert it.

I am trying the following

```
etSearch.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            //I want to create an observable here to send events
               Observable.create(e->e.next(p0));
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }
    })
```

I am not able to figure out where i should create my events so that i am able to subscribe to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply create an extension in `kotlin` which returns a `Flowable` of `EditTextFlow`

```
fun EditText.addTextWatcher(): Flowable<EditTextFlow> {
    return Flowable.create<EditTextFlow>({ emitter ->
        addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                emitter.onNext(EditTextFlow(p0.toString(), EditTextFlow.Type.BEFORE))
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
                emitter.onNext(EditTextFlow(p0.toString(), EditTextFlow.Type.ON))
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                emitter.onNext(EditTextFlow(p0.toString(), EditTextFlow.Type.AFTER))
            }
        })
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
}
```

**EditTextFlow**

```
data class EditTextFlow(
        val query: String,
        val type: Type
) {
    enum class Type { BEFORE, AFTER, ON }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
etSearch.addTextWatcher()
                .filter { it.type == EditTextFlow.Type.AFTER }
                .map { it.query }
                .flatMap { /*Make any request or anything*/ }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeBy(
                        onNext = {
                            // Update UI here
                        },
                        onError = {
                            // Log error
                        }
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a [library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) for this.

You can use it as

```
RxTextView.textChanges(etSearch)
```

Comment: i don't want to use Rxbinding library